# string interpolation for double-quoted attribute value in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, erb, template-engine

How can I write a double-quoted attribute-escaped erb expression and get the correct escaping behavior?

For example, I'd like something that will output:

```
value="Hello World"
```

if `should_print_value` is true, and assuming `myvalue` = `Hello World`

**Edit**: Note: `myvalue` may contain malicious content

**Approach 1**

If I try something like

```
<%= "value=\"#{myvalue}\"" if should_print_value %>
```

erb will escape the double quotes, resulting in `value=&quotHello` and another attribute named `World&quot=""`

**Approach 2**

The simplest solution I've come up with is to do:

```
<% if should_print_value %>
  value="<%= myvalue %>"
<% end %>
```

But I'm still curious as to if it's possible using the `<%= "value=.... %>` syntax of Approach 1.

Comment: try `"value=\"#{myvalue}\"".html_safe`. What are you trying to achieve? There might be an easier way.

Comment: I forgot to specify, `myvalue` is untrusted and may contain malicious XSS content, so `.html_safe` is not acceptable

Comment: answering your question, I'm simply trying to conditionally add a `value` attribute to an HTML element in an erb template (among other conditional attributes). In my case it's a text input tag.

Answer (score 2):

As @BroiSatse pointed out, either use:

```
<%= "value=\"#{myvalue}\"".html_safe if should_print_value %>
```

or, which I would prefer in views:

```
<%= raw "value=\"#{myvalue}\"" if should_print_value %>
```

This will mark the content as safe, however you will need to pay attention that the `myvalue` isn't malicous. You can use a method like `CGI.escape` to correctly format special characters that might be a security risk.

Comment: That is correct, I forgot to specify that `myvalue` is potentially malicious. I would prefer to not use `.html_safe` or `raw` because many people collaborate on this code and using either of those raises red flags

Comment: If you just escape your `myvalue` with `CGI.escape`, you can use `raw` and `.html_safe` without any problems ;)

Comment: This is the only inline solution there is actually, since otherwise the quotes will always be escaped when printing it out. http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape

Answer (score 1):

If you're committed to an inline solution, `<input ...value="<%= myvalue if should_print_value %>">` should insert a properly escaped `myvalue` or an empty string (effectively telling the input to be empty), depending on `should_print_value`. I'd probably just go with your Approach 2, as I find it somewhat clearer.